# Retrofit 2 always returns onFailure

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I can not understand the problem. Always returns onFailure.
Data returns status code 200, OnResponse does not return.

Response 
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.10.10/oauth/token (667ms)

What's wrong with this code?

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static ApiBackend api;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.10.10/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .client(client)
                .build();
        api = retrofit.create(ApiBackend.class);
    }

    public static ApiBackend getApi() {
        return api;
    }
}
```

Interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("oauth/token")
Call<List<AuthModel>> auth(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
        @Field("client_id") Integer client_id,
        @Field(

"client_secret") String client_secret
            );
```

AuthModel

```
public class AuthModel {
    List<AuthModel> TaskModel;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("grant_type")
    @Expose
    private String grantType;
    @SerializedName("client_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer clientId;
    @SerializedName("client_secret")
    @Expose
    private String clientSecret;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getGrantType() {
        return grantType;
    }

    public void setGrantType(String grantType) {
        this.grantType = grantType;
    }

    public Integer getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(Integer clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getClientSecret() {
        return clientSecret;
    }

    public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
        App.getApi().auth("admin@admin.com","admin123","password",2,"yl9s3UK74vSR1AxlCMhHqHO1AbTz9DzaXUVZyKpA").enqueue(new Callback<List<AuthModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<AuthModel>> call, Response<List<AuthModel>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
              Log.v(TAG,"ffff");
            } else {
                // error response, no access to resource?
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<AuthModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Probably an issue with your response failing to be mapped to your model. 1. what does your json response look like and 2. should your auth method return a List of AuthModel or just a single AuthModel?

Comment: Json response {
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 31536000,}  
There must be two different models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are failing to understand how to use the Retrofit library.

Lets have a look at method you have declared in your service Interface.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("oauth/token")
Call<List<AuthModel>> auth(
    @Field("username") String username,
    @Field("password") String password,
    @Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
    @Field("client_id") Integer client_id,
    @Field(

"client_secret") String client_secret
        );
```

The line `Call<List<AuthModel>>` is telling retrofit what the response of the api call will look like. What you are telling it to do here is to expect something that looks like your AuthModel, not only that but a List of AuthModels.

What you actually need to do is to

1. create a class that represents the response `{ "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 31536000}` and
2. declare that as the expected response of your auth method call like so `Call<MyFunkyNewLoginResponseClass>`

If you are still experiencing problems after that then that should warrant a separate question.

Comment: Created model https://gist.github.com/Asetss/4e2303ad932434a471403f2adb4f5b28     api https://gist.github.com/Asetss/c3dba9c76855fa977a8b214161e5956e              error 
in Call cannot be applied

Comment: And your interface?

Comment: interface https://gist.github.com/Asetss/3e0fed45a0c163249fb92ccd9a36eaef

Comment: I forked your interface Gist and altered it.

Comment: Saw the console log. Change api https://gist.github.com/Asetss/c3dba9c76855fa977a8b214161e5956e  Removed model AuthResponseModel

Comment: You should accept the answer to help others with the same problem in future.